# neo4j return 1 node with maximum property value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a root "company" node, and it will have several relating "report" nodes, each of which has a timestamp property (millisec).

I want to get the "newest" report node for a company, which basically translates to "get 1 node where max(x)" but I dont know if that is possible in cipher

in theory, I could do the following

```
match (c:company)->(r:report) WHERE r.timestamp order by DESC LIMIT 1
```

But i want to also be able to get other types of the "newest" nodes. Ultimately I want to get this type of results:

```
(company)-->(Report [newest version])
         -->(twitterCountObject [newest version])
         -->(employeeCountObject [newest version])
```

How do I accomplish this in cypher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. Something like this should work:

```
MATCH (c:Company {name: "ABC"})-->(r:Report),
      (c)-->(t:TwitterCount),
      (c)-->(e:EmployeeCount)
RETURN c, r, t, e
ORDER BY r.timestamp DESC, t.timestamp DESC, e.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: thank you very much. that just piqued my interest in another way: is it possible to return *all* the newest 1 node per *each* type where the `relationship is [r:someRelation]` without specifying the ligand node types like lines 2,3 above?

Comment: That does not seem trivial, and deserves its own SO question.